# LiteTouchPE.wim and Boot.wim taking ages to download

Tags: wds, mdt

I have an MDT/WDS server (VM) with both MDT and WDS installed on it. I've had this server for a few years, with several WDS/MDT deployments happening from it each day (automated). I've never had an issue with the server previously.

Last week we move the VM to a different ESXi host, hosted in a different data centre, and all of a sudden the LiteTouchPE_x64.wim and Boot.wim has been taking ages to load. Below is a screenshot showing the loading screen I'm talking about.

[image]

When this was running in our old data centre, this loading screen would only show for a few seconds. Now, it is taking several hours.

Below is the troubleshooting we've done so far:

1. We're not experiencing any issues on the ESXi host the MDT/WDS server is running on.
2. Both the WDS server and PXE client are running on the same ESXi host (so it doesn't feel as though this is a networking issue).
3. I've tried importing the drivers into MDT for our Lenovo ST50 (the ESXi host), and that hasn't changed the performance.

Does anyone know what would cause the boot wims to run so slow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

For anyone else experiencing the same, you need to:

1. Within vCentre, on the client computer, switch the Network Adapter Type to  `VMXNET 3`.
2. Go to a VM on the same host, and import the vmxnet 3 drivers under into MDT. Those drivers can be found under:
   `C:\Program Files\Common Files\VMware\Drivers`. Note: This VM should have the VMware system tools installed.
3. Update the MDT Deployment share, then import the updated `LiteTouchPE_x64.wim` into WDS under `Boot images`.

After that, everything should be good to go.